# Assigning a default value to a LONGLONG type. Mingw GCC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mingw

I am porting some code and came across this

```
class Someclass
{
   void Restart (IN TIMEX_STAMP rtMinTime = 0I64);
};
```

This code works fine in visual studio however in Mingw GCC I get the error

```
error: expected ')' before ';' token|
error: unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator"" I64'|
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this code ?

Comment: If you're assigning a value of 0, why not just use 0 and let the compiler convert it appropriately?

Comment: I have inherited this piece of code and am not sure about the reason

Comment: @JamesFranco: If you're not sure then how can we be? Lol. Ask the author. When he failed to leave behind any documenting comments, he made it so that he's the only one who can tell you the intent of the code. If nothing else, we have no idea what `TIMEX_STAMP` is.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal suffix `I64` is a [Visual C++ extension that specifies a 64-bit signed integer type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00a1awxf.aspx). [`0LL`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) is probably close enough in standard C++, although `long long` is technically specified to have *at least* 64 bits. If you're paranoid, there's always [`std::int64_t{0}`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: A simple `0` is also close enough. `0` is of type `int`, but the assignment will implicitly convert it to any scalar type.

Comment: @KeithThompson We don't know what a `TIMEX_STAMP` is. If it's a scalar type - which is likely, given the title of the question - `0` is great. If it's a class type, conversion of `0` to `TIMEX_STAMP` could result in completely different behavior than conversion of `0LL`. I'm inclined to be wary, given that the original author didn't put a `0` there in the first place.

Comment: Good point. But I suggest that if conversion of `0` and `0LL` cause completely different behavior, then `TIMEX_STAMP` is poorly designed and error-prone. And if `0` and `0LL` differ in behavior, then I wouldn't want to assume that `0LL` and `std::int64_t{0}` behave the same way.